# I need to change the path and use the newly changed path

Tags: dll, inno-setup

We are using a really old Intel math library (nsp.dll and family) and it's location must be specified in the Windows PATH variable.  Previously we installed these dll's in the Windows/System32 folder so everything was fine.  Now we would like to install these dll's in another folder, the reason is we are migrating to Windows 7 and do not want to place dll's in the System32 folder.  I found the SO answer as to how to change the PATH variable (thanks for that) and that does work. After installing I checked the PATH and our folder was NOT added to the PATH, I check the reg key and our folder WAS added. But....it appears that when we register our OCX that uses those dll's, the path is not changed yet. When I rebooted the PATH has our added path.

So, it seems I'm in a catch-22, I need to change the PATH and also use the new PATH during the install. Do I need to require a reboot and some how register that OCX after the reboot?  Or is there another way?

After the reboot, running cmd as Administrator allowed me to register the OCX in the new folder. But I would like to have the installer do this automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the following setting in your script:

```
[Setup]
ChangesEnvironment=yes
```

This will allow the PATH change to take effect without a reboot.

**However** it will only affect new processes started by the shell.  If you have an existing cmd window, or you try to start the application at the end of the install *without* using the `shellexec` flag, it will still see the old PATH.

---

And double-**however**: you cannot legally change the path where a COM DLL or OCX file is installed and registered.  These must without exception be installed in the location specified by the vendor.  Hence you must continue to install it in `{sys}` anyway.  (At least if you're still using system-wide registration.  There is an alternative that does let you move it, if you look up "registration-free COM", but it comes with a lot of caveats and is seldom worth the effort.)

Also note that "because Windows 7" is not a valid reason to move something anyway.

Comment: Thanks I will try the ChangesEnvironment and shellexec flag. We were given directions to install "everything" under \program files\companyname\appname (no exceptions). I'll mention the lawyer's legalese and probably be allowed to install things where ever is easiest. I did not know that the location of installed files was protected by some sort of rights. But I'd like to try your suggestions for the learning experience.

Comment: It's not rights as such, it's just that `regserver` is a global registration -- every single application must use the same location (and typically must use `sharedfile` too).  Otherwise installing or uninstalling your app might break someone else's, and vice versa.

Comment: In the end I just installed into {sys} and got on with my life. Ours is the only application that will be installed on the computer. Turn-key type system.